# Count multiple lines between timestamps as one line

Tags: bash, logging

How can I count with "linux board tools" (wc, sed, ...) errors in a log file?

Example log lines

```
2023-09-25 11:11:02.4594
2023-09-25 11:12:02.9254
2023-09-25 11:13:03.0777
2023-09-25 11:14:02.4585
fetchmail: WARNING: imap.xy.z.ch configuration invalid, you normally need port 993/service imaps for --ssl.
fetchmail: OpenSSL reported: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
fetchmail: imap.xy.z.ch : SSL connection failed.
fetchmail: socket error while fetching from user@xy.ch@imap.xy.z.ch
2023-09-25 11:15:02.6085
fetchmail: WARNING: imap.xy.z.ch configuration invalid, you normally need port 993/service imaps for --ssl.
fetchmail: OpenSSL reported: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
fetchmail: imap.xy.z.ch : SSL connection failed.
fetchmail: socket error while fetching from user@xy.ch@imap.xy.z.ch
2023-09-25 11:16:02.2786
fetchmail: WARNING: imap.xy.z.ch configuration invalid, you normally need port 993/service imaps for --ssl.
fetchmail: OpenSSL reported: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
fetchmail: imap.xy.z.ch : SSL connection failed.
fetchmail: socket error while fetching from user@xy.ch@imap.xy.z.ch
2023-09-25 11:17:02.5138
fetchmail:/somewhere/my.fetchmail:13: syntax error at user
2023-09-25 11:18:02.7093
2023-09-25 11:19:02.9584
2023-09-25 11:20:02.5294
```

Currently I count every line which is not a timestamp.

Result: 13 "errors"

But the "real" counter should by 4 errors.

As "complex" solution I'm trying something like that. But I hope a better solution exist for my problem? :)

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
        echo "Log filename required - stopping"
        exit 1
fi
# Set log file name
logFile=$1

# Set variables
found=0
shortDate=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

echo "** Beginn..."

# Wake through file
while read line
do
        curr=${line:0:10}
        if [ "$last" == "" ]; then
                 last=${line:0:10}
        fi
        if [ "$last" != "$curr" ]; then
                if [ "$curr" != "$shortDate" ]; then
                        let found+=1
                fi
        fi
        last=$curr
done < $logFile
echo $found
```

Output is now 4 :)

Comment: Thanks for your solutions - each of them works.

Comment: Can your log file ever start with a line that is not a date? If so, some of the answers you have will fail to count that initial failure report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{p=f; f=(/^[0-9]/)} (p != "0") && !f{cnt++} END{print cnt+0}' file
4
```

The above just sets a flag `f` when the line starts with a date (the only lines of your input that start with a number are dates) and then whenever the previous line started with a date (`p` is set to `1`) but current line does not start with a date (`f` is set to `0`), it increments the count of those date->non-date transitions which it then prints at the end of reading the input.

I'm using `p != "0"` instead of just `p` so that if the input file started with a failure message rather than a date it'd still be counted (because in that case `p` would contain the null string rather than the number `1` as it would if the previous line had been a date), e.g.:

```
$ cat file
fetchmail: WARNING: imap.xy.z.ch configuration invalid, you normally need port 993/service imaps for --ssl.
fetchmail: OpenSSL reported: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
fetchmail: imap.xy.z.ch : SSL connection failed.
fetchmail: socket error while fetching from user@xy.ch@imap.xy.z.ch
2023-09-25 11:11:02.4594
2023-09-25 11:12:02.9254
2023-09-25 11:13:03.0777
2023-09-25 11:14:02.4585
fetchmail: WARNING: imap.xy.z.ch configuration invalid, you normally need port 993/service imaps for --ssl.
fetchmail: OpenSSL reported: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
fetchmail: imap.xy.z.ch : SSL connection failed.
fetchmail: socket error while fetching from user@xy.ch@imap.xy.z.ch
2023-09-25 11:15:02.6085
fetchmail: WARNING: imap.xy.z.ch configuration invalid, you normally need port 993/service imaps for --ssl.
fetchmail: OpenSSL reported: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
fetchmail: imap.xy.z.ch : SSL connection failed.
fetchmail: socket error while fetching from user@xy.ch@imap.xy.z.ch
2023-09-25 11:16:02.2786
fetchmail: WARNING: imap.xy.z.ch configuration invalid, you normally need port 993/service imaps for --ssl.
fetchmail: OpenSSL reported: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
fetchmail: imap.xy.z.ch : SSL connection failed.
fetchmail: socket error while fetching from user@xy.ch@imap.xy.z.ch
2023-09-25 11:17:02.5138
fetchmail:/somewhere/my.fetchmail:13: syntax error at user
2023-09-25 11:18:02.7093
2023-09-25 11:19:02.9584
2023-09-25 11:20:02.5294
```

```
$ awk '{p=f; f=(/^[0-9]/)} (p != "0") && !f{cnt++} END{print cnt+0}' file
5
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{4}' '
    !/^[[:space:]]*$/ {c++}
    END {
        print c+0
    }
' file.log
```

- Assigning `RS` to a timestamp pattern, the input log file is splitted on it.
- Non-error line is empty or blank characters at most. The variable `c`
  counts error lines only.

Comment: Very informative and nice answer, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -A1` to output the lines following the timestamps. Then remove the timestamps and grep separators to get the actual errors.

```bash
timestamp='^[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$'

grep -A1 "$timestamp" file | grep -v "$timestamp\|^--$" | wc -l
```

The only problem might be when the error itself starts with a `--` on a single line.

Comment: For me that is the easiest version - many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I converted new line to space and used regex to filter content between timestamps and removed empty lines and then count number of lines.

```
cat test.txt | tr "\n" " " | grep -Po "(?<=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{4}).+?(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{4}|$)" |
 grep -v -e '^[[:space:]]*$' | wc -l
```

Your can refactor duplicate date formats.